# Setting route in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to set a route so that if I hit `http://localhost:8080/user/beta/`, it redirects to `http://localhost:8080/user/beta/#spreadsheet`,
 and shows the spreadsheet view, but my code is redirecting to: `http://localhost:8080/#spreadsheet`.

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import {Spreadsheet} from './components/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'spreadsheet', terminal: true },
  { path: 'spreadsheet', component: Spreadsheet }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to have the `#` before the last path segment?

Comment: Yes since we already have an app in which if user logged in then all the navigation happens like this only /user/notification, user/search, this was in javascript/jquery & now re-writing everything in angular2 so still requirement is same.

Comment: Maybe you want to switch to `HashLocationStrategy`.

Comment: Its also the same right? (For instance, if I call location.go('/spreadsheet'), the browser's URL will become example.com#/spreadsheet)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the same". I guess not. If you use `router.navigate('/spreadsheet')` then it should become `example.com#/spreadsheet`. Maybe you need to add `<base href="/user/beta">` to get ``example.com/user/beta/#/spreadsheet` but I still don't get what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: well yes setting base URL did what i needed... thanks.. can you please post it as an answer

Comment: Done. I guess the desired result can only be accomplished with `HashLocationStrategy`, right?

Comment: yes correct, right now in my case as per my manager's requirement in beta navigation should be done like /user/beta#/spreadsheet, /user/beta#/pannel, /user/beta#/cards & with base href set to "/" it was not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HashLocationStrategy` with `<base href="/user/beta">` to define what part of the URL is static.

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ' '

Comment: Still getting same error after your edit (terminal removed)